# RefreshControl bugs first Cell of TableView, after using Back on NavBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a TableView embedded in NavigationController (and that's embedded in a TabBar Controller). I have a username button in each cell that segues to the user's profile.

[image]

However after I hit 'back' on the profile page's nav bar, and gets directed back to tableview, it seems like I bugged something.

[image]

[image]

And if I pull down again, it refreshs but this time, top row's username becomes unclickable while other rows work as expected.

Please note that I call `self.theRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()` in `viewDidLoad` in tableView but I am not sure if it is or isn't getting called, after using Back button.

Please note that I perform segue with `prepareForSegue`.

---

**To wrap up**

- If I go to the notifications page and try clicking username, username button click  and segue works
- If I go to the notifications, and pull the refresh, username button in first row doesn't work
- If I go to the notifications and don't do any refresh, the username buttons segues and back works (so it doesn't bug).
- If I go to the notifications and pull to refresh, the refreshControl icon appears and disappears, but now, it doesn't let me click on the username button on the top row.
- If I do refresh on notifications, it doesn't let me click on the username in the top row. If I click on the second username in the second cell, it segues to user's profile, but when I click back button, then it bugs like this:

[image]

**Code in ViewDidLoad():**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.theRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
  self.theRefreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
  self.theRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
  self.tableView.addSubview(theRefreshControl)
}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
   if isFirstLoad == false {
      currentPage = 1
       getStuff()
    }

   self.theRefreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

I also tried adding `self.tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl` above and below `self.tableView.addSubview(theRefreshControl)`; and also tried replacing `self.tableView.addSubview(theRefreshControl)` with `self.tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl` but unfortunately no luck

Comment: It works fine before the segue?

Comment: Yes, username button works fine before segue. I just realised that if I go to that page, and don't pull to refresh, it works fine.. However as soon as I pull down (so trigger refresh), then it fails to do the segue again on username button click.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475792/how-to-use-pull-to-refresh-in-swift

Comment: @Maheshreddy I did exactly same with [this answer provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24476087/4705339). Also I made the refresh control working on the other page, which is working. And I am trying to do the same thing here, but not working properly.

Comment: My guess is that your refreshControl is in front of your cells, so as a last effort try this: `tableView.sendSubviewToBack(theRefreshControl)` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Va laaa.. Your solution magically worked! Please add it as an answer and I accept the bounty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way you should instantiate the refreshControl is like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl // <- THIS!!!
}
```

as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33524757/5007134).

My guess is that your refreshControl is in front of your cells, so if the above doesn't work try this: `tableView.sendSubviewToBack(theRefreshControl)` in `viewDidLoad`

**EDIT**: Since `tableView.sendSubviewToBack(theRefreshControl)` was the solution, consider filing a bug with Apple, since it should happen automatically when you set the `refreshControl` as the `tableView.backgroundView`

Comment: Mine looks quite similar to this, except the line `tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl`. (Please check my updated answer, I just added my code in ViewDidLoad). I tried adding `tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl` both before and after `self.tableView.addSubview(theRefreshControl)` but unfortunately, no luck

Comment: You have to remove `self.tableView.addSubview:`. Also, do you call `endRefreshing:`?

Comment: Yes, I am calling. `self.theRefreshControl.endRefreshing()`. I am adding my code in the question. Just a sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!! This `sendSubviewToBack` solved my problem. So I used `tableView.addSubview(theRefreshControl)` and  `tableView.sendSubviewToBack(theRefreshControl)`. I didn't use `tableView.backgroundView = refreshControl`. @Quan~, again, thanks a lot man. I'll accept the bounty when it lets me in 23hrs.. XoXo

Comment: No problem, always a pleasure! :)